# How to design a controller for a non inverting bidirectional buck boost converter?

Tags: power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, converter

This is the circuit diagram that i made in matlab.  I want in to design a controller for the it such that it works as a boost converter in one direction and buck in the other direction. But i don't know how to implement it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

At least you could simplify it:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAFgwJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

buck mode:

- M1 turns on for specified duty time with regard to stepping down ratio
- M2 synchronously switches on while M1 is off
- M2 also switches off if a back flow is detected with comparator CMP2

boost mode:

- M2 turns on for specified duty time with regard to stepping up ratio
- M1 synchronously switches on while M2 is off
- M1 also switches off if a back flow is detected with comparator CMP1

Code:

```
if (V1/10) * hyst  > V2 then
    do buck()
else if V2*10 * hyst > V1 then
    do boost()
else 
    do nothing()
end_if
```